# Java Persistence Criteria API - case expressions in orderBy()

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I need to order the result of my query by a field if not null otherwise by another field.

This is my code:

```
Expression condizione=cb.isNotNull(root.get(Attribuzione_.dataprincipale));
Expression principale=root.get(Attribuzione_.dataprincipale);
Expression creato=root.get(Attribuzione_.recordcreato);
Order ord=cb.desc(cb.selectCase()
        .when(condizione, principale)
        .otherwise(creato));
cq=cq.orderBy(ord);
```

This code causes an `Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`
because the translation in SQL code is not the "order by" I need:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (t0.dataprincipale IS NOT NULL) THEN (t0.dataprincipale IS NOT NULL) ELSE t0.rec_creato END  DESC
```

instead of

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (t0.dataprincipale IS NOT NULL) THEN t0.dataprincipale ELSE t0.rec_creato END  DESC
```

But I don't understand where is the fault in my code.

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using EclipseLink 2.3.x or older, try to upgrade to a recent one.

I've tested your code with 2.3.x and fails, but from 2.4.x seams to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Place the expression in an extra column, and orderBy that column. The same as in SQL.

Comment: In Postrgres SQL I normally write `ORDER BY CASE ... THEN  ... ELSE ... END` ;)  
  
Do you mean  

`SELECT t0.*, CASE WHEN (t0.dataprincipale IS NOT NULL) THEN t0.dataprincipale ELSE t0.rec_creato END AS orderby_data
FROM Attribuzione t0
ORDER BY orderby_data`

?

I try to translate it in Criteria API. It's my first approach...

Thank you

Comment: SQL historically has a restricted expressiveness for ORDER BY columns. JPA typically implements SQL dialects a bit later and less complete. Staying close to a standard SQL still has its advantage.

Answer (score 0):

No way. I'm afraid of it's an Eclipse bug (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461) :(

Do you know about a bug in Eclipse?

The code

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cqt= cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Attribuzione> roott = cqt.from(Attribuzione.class);
cqt.multiselect(cb.selectCase()
            .when(cb.isNotNull(roott.get(Attribuzione_.dataprincipale)), roott.get(Attribuzione_.dataprincipale))
            .otherwise(roott.get(Attribuzione_.recordcreato)), roott);
cqt = cqt.where(cb.equal(roott.get(Attribuzione_.esecutoreprincipale), "pivamichela"));
TypedQuery<Tuple> tq = em.createQuery(cqt);
```

generate this SQL code (with the same error as in the "order by")

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (dataprincipale IS NOT NULL) THEN (dataprincipale IS NOT NULL) ELSE rec_creato END , ID, dataletto, dataprincipale, esecutoreletto, esecutoreprincipale, evidenza, letto, principale, rec_creato, rec_creato_da, rec_modificato, rec_modificato_da, protocollo, ufficio FROM PROTOCOLLO.ATTRIBUZIONE WHERE (esecutoreprincipale = ?)
```